# SharePoint Configuration Wizard Error - The SDDL string contains an invalid SID or a SID that cannot be translated

Tags: sharepoint, windows-server-2012

While installing SharePoint Server 2013 I am finding the above error in the Configuration Wizard.

This error is occurred while generating Sample Data for SQL.

It gives me an error in the 8th step out of 10 steps.

I have tried to find out the solution for that and I have came to know that I need to set Full Access rights permission for WSS_ADMIN_WPG user.

But I did not find any folder that starts with "Analytics_GUID" in the "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\15.0\Data\Office" Server Path.

Can anyone help me out in this.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem.  You also need to ensure that the account you are installing with has sufficient permissions in the SHAREPOINT SQL Server instance.

To grant your account sufficient SQL permissions:

1. open SQL Server Management Studio
2. connect to the SHAREPOINT instance ( named server\SHAREPOINT )
3. in the left tree expand Security | Logins and select your account
4. right click and select Properties
5. in the login properties dialog select Server Roles
6. select all of the checkboxes to grant yourself every role.
7. click ok.

See this article for details: http://www.sharepointpitstop.com/2013/09/the-sddl-string-contains-invalid-sid-or.html

Following is the pertinent part of the article:

> 1) Check if the account used for installing SharePoint 2013 has dbcreator and security admin permission in SQL Server.
>
> 2) Browse to "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\15.0\Data\Office Server" and find the folder that starts with Analytics_GUID.
>
> 3) Right-click -> Properties ->Sharing ->Advanced Sharing. Check the "Share this folder' check box and click on Permissions.
>
> 4) Granted full access to everyone.
>
> 5) Added WSS_ADMIN_WPG to the sharing with full access.
>
> 6) Ran the SharePoint 2013 Products Configuration Wizard again and this completed successfully.

Comment: Thank you! With the database permission change and the sharing it worked!I had first tried sharing the parent folder for everyone + WSS_ADMIN_WPG, but it apparently had to be the exact folder, also not 100% but I added all the WSS_ accounts to have full access.