# Microsoft Sharepoint 2019 install Search service application error

Tags: sharepoint

I got the below error during standard SharePoint 2019 configuration in Standalone mode on a Windows Server 2019 standard. SharePoint 2019 Installation was successful. This happened while i configuration the server search application, the configuration failed and I got the below error.
my step:
1. login central admin page 
2. Application Management -> Service Applications -> Manage service applications 
3. Click "New" button 
4. Select "Search Service Application" 
5. Enter application pool name and use LOCAL admin account to create.

Error message below :

The service application "Search Service Application" could not be created because of the following error: System.ArgumentException: The SDDL string contains an invalid sid or a sid that cannot be translated. Parameter name: sddlForm at System.Security.AccessControl.RawSecurityDescriptor.BinaryFormFromSddlForm(String sddlForm) at Microsoft.SharePoint.Win32.SPNetApi32.CreateFileShareWithSecurity(String name, String description, String path, String sddl) at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.AnalyticsAdministration.CreateAnalyticsUNCShare(String dirParentLocation, String shareName) at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.AnalyticsAdministration.ProvisionAnalyticsShare(SearchServiceApplication serviceApplication) at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.AnalyticsAdministration.CreateDefaultStoreLocation(SearchServiceApplication serviceApplication) at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.AnalyticsAdministration.ProvisionRawEventStore(SearchServiceApplication serviceApplication) at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.AnalyticsServiceAdministration.Provision() at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplication.Provision() at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchAdminUtils.UpdateIgnoreSPUpdatedConcurrencyException(String description, SearchAdminUtilsUpdateDelegate updateDelegate, SearchAdminUtilsRefreshObjectDelegate refreshObjectDelegate) at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchConfigWizard.CreateSearchApp() at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchConfigWizard.ProvisionSearchServiceApplication() at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchConfigurationJobDefinition.ExecuteTimerJob()

P.S :  i have try many methods like below... 
1. https://collab365.community/the-sddl-string-contains-an-invalid-sid-or-a-sid-that-cannot-be/

2. Change the server role from "single farm" to "application and search"

3. [SharePoint Configuration Wizard Error - The SDDL string contains an invalid SID or a SID that cannot be translated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21259839/sharepoint-configuration-wizard-error-the-sddl-string-contains-an-invalid-sid?rq=1)

4. https://www.eltallerdesharepoint.com/net/error-the-sddl-string-contains-an-invalid-sid-or-a-sid-that-cannot-be-translated/

**PLEASE HELP ME.......**

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i solve it.
First of all, in SharePoint 2019 you MUST join a domain, there are no choice.

https://veronicageek.com/sharepoint/sharepoint-2013/create-the-search-service-application-in-sharepoint-server-using-powershell/2018/03/